# PDF/eBook reader with horizontal scrolling feature instead of vertical

Tags: pdf, sync, cloud, adobe-reader, nextcloud

So far all the readers I experienced scroll pages vertically, while fitting horizontally A4 pages' width.

Are there softwares out there able to:

1. "swipe left" pages
2. fit vertically both A4 and A3 pages (which have the same height) to the portrait-oriented screen
3. compatible with linux and android
4. must have would be some comment-stick/highlight/draw-on features
5. cherry on the top would be integrated sync to both centralized and self-hosted clouds
   ?

Sometimes pdf files include portrait-oriented A4 pages, with landscape-oriented A3 pages, and it's a pain in the ass having to resize at each switch...
[image]

Answer (score 1):

xpdf has horizontal scrolling but no annotation or integrated sync unfortunately

[image: screenshot]

It must be manually downloaded and installed from their website: https://www.xpdfreader.com/

Comment: Please replace the link with an `apt install <something>` command

Comment: Not available on apt. Will clarify answer.